# Stream from S3 a MP4 video file from a Grails controller to a video.js player

Tags: grails, amazon-s3, video.js

I have an issue trying to stream MP4 video files from Amazon S3 through a grails controller.  I would like to host a video file on S3 and stream it (or send it) through a grails controller, that will be accessed by the front end that is a video.js player in a html page.

I need to keep the videos on S3 private, so just making the video public on S3 and using a direct url is not possible.  Any help is appreciated.

Controller:

```
def video = {
  def s3 = amazonWebService.s3
  def file = s3.getObject(params.bucketName, params.key)

  response.status = 206
  response.contentType = "video/mp4"
  response.outputStream << file.objectContent
  response.outputStream.flush()
  response.outputStream.close()
```

}

Video (GSP frontend):

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
      controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
        <source src="${createLink(controller:'home', action:'video', params:[bucketName:bucketInstance, key:videoFileInstance])}" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What problem are you experiencing? Your question doesn't state what the actual issue is, only what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  I am not getting an error, but the video file that I am trying to play in video.js isn't playing.  I am not sure what I am missing.  Any suggestions for setting up a better debug environment would be of help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download the video.

1. Use the AWS Java SDK, get pre_signed URL for the video, using your bucket and key details. If your video is not of confidential nature, you can also create get a public URL for the video.
2. Use that pre-signed URL in the place of the SRC.
3. The video would still not play correctly in all the browsers, because you are having only one format MP4 in your video, which is not supported in all the browsers. You would need to upload the webm format as well to S3 and provide the URL for it in the videojs SRC for that format. For this you can use AWS video encoder, or you can use ffmpeg to do the conversion.

Finally you would be able to play the video in all the major browsers.

Hope this helps.